# How to search something on NSMutableArray using predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a `NSMutableArray` it has several dictionary objects like this.

```
"DisplayName": "ART42 - Jomon Williams", 
    "DisplayName2": "Jomon Williams", 
    "EmployeeNumber": "ART42", 
    "Designation": "Senior Executive - Systems",
```

I have a `UITextField` when its text changing I want to reload my `UITableView` with search filtered array. For Searching I did something like this. When my text is changing im doing this.

```
    NSPredicate *exists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    NSLog(@"Predicate-------%@",exists);

    NSArray *aList = [mutArrayStaff filteredArrayUsingPredicate:exists];
```

I want to search by `DisplayName2`key. Everytime my `aList` array is empty. How can I write my predicate correctly inorder to search on `DisplayName2`

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `mutArrayStaff` is a list of dictionaries, each of them containing `DisplayName2` as the key, you can do the following:

```
NSPredicate *exists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(DisplayName2 CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText];
```